# How to move camera in webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I started to learn webgl, but it's very hard, so I dont know a lot of things. How do I move the camera in the 3D space and how do I set, where to focus?

Answer (score 6):

WebGL is quite low level and doesn't support cameras as such. If you want to see details please refer to [this tutorial](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1067) which is a part of a big tutorial series you might find helpful.

I would recommend you to have a look at [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) which is a lighweight 3D engine built on top of WebGL. See [this HTML presentation](http://fhtr.org/BasicsOfThreeJS/#1) for a nice introduction into this library.

Comment: in three.js I can create cameras, and I can move them. How it works in three.js?